# adding linker to command line

Tags: opencv, linker

I am trying to compile a project and you can find the makefile at this link here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/95042389/Makefile

I have installed ANN and OpenCV 2.3.1.

When I type make, it is returning the errors given below.

sai@sai-HP-EliteBook-8460w:~/workspace/4pcs$ make 
g++ -L/home/sai/workspace/OpenCV-2.4.1/lib -L/home/sai/workspace/ann_1.1.2/lib -L/usr/lib 4pcs.o 4pcs_test.o -o 4pcs -lopencv_highgui -lANN -o 4pcs
/usr/bin/ld: 4pcs.o: undefined reference to symbol 'cv::operator*(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'cv::operator*(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&)' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [4pcs] Error 1

Then I tried this

sai@sai-HP-EliteBook-8460w:~/workspace/4pcs$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/usr/lib:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib:/opt/ros/fuerte/lib:/usr/lib/libopencv_core.2.3

Still the same errors..

Any suggestions?

Comment: The subject is too vague for the specific question asked here.  I came here, misled by the summary.  Please supply a summary to more accurately describes the posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by adding

-lopencv_core and then it worked with no errors.